# getting the screen density programmatically in android?

Tags: android, dpi, screen-density

How to get the screen density programmatically in android?

I mean: How to find the screen dpi of the current device?

Comment: Many answers refer to `getDisplayMetrics().xdpi`, which is supposed to return the real dpi of the device. Please note that this value is *not consistently set correctly across devices* by the manufacturers, so you *just can't use them*. Sad but true: **the information about real dpi is not available**. Source: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/g56jV0Hora0/9d8p8QJg1ksJ

Comment: `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().xdpi` and `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().ydpi` will give you **actual horizontal and vertical densities**, which are in most cases different.

Answer (score 567, accepted):

You can get info on the display from the [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) struct:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
```

Though Android doesn't use a direct pixel mapping, it uses a handful of quantized Density Independent Pixel values then scales to the actual screen size. So the `metrics.densityDpi` property will be one of the `DENSITY_xxx` constants (`120`, `160`, `213`, `240`, `320`, `480` or `640` dpi).

If you need the *actual* lcd pixel density (perhaps for an OpenGL app) you can get it from the `metrics.xdpi` and `metrics.ydpi` properties for horizontal and vertical density respectively.

If you are targeting API Levels earlier than 4. The `metrics.density` property is a floating point scaling factor from the reference density (160dpi). The same value now provided by `metrics.densityDpi` can be calculated

```
int densityDpi = (int)(metrics.density * 160f);
```

Comment: Granted this post is from over two years ago, but this is the first thing that comes up on Google for this search, so for anyone who finds this, you no longer have to multiply by 160.

Comment: No longer since which version?

Comment: I've updated the answer to match the latest API revisions that people may be using.

Comment: Note: You may want this newer API instead: `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(metrics);`  This was officially added in API 17, but I was surprised to find that it worked correctly even on a 4.0 device I tried.

Comment: If you go into the Android documentation and set your API to API 15, this line of code is displayed... so it may have been added in API 15.

Comment: @roboguy12 I tried not multiplying it by 160, and it showed 4. multiplying by 160 using the code in the answer above, requires multiplying by 160

Comment: @Polarbear0106 If you are using the `density` property you will need to multiply by 160. In API levels >= 4 you can use the `xdpi` and `ydpi` or the `desnityDpi` properties to get scalar values.

Comment: there is also getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi

Comment: now 'getDefaultDisplay()' is deprecated  & 'getMetrics(android.util.DisplayMetrics)' is deprecated help me

Answer (score 413):

This also works:

```
 getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

This will give you:

0.75 - ldpi

1.0 - mdpi

1.5 - hdpi

2.0 - xhdpi

3.0 - xxhdpi

4.0 - xxxhdpi

[image]

[ref: density](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#density)

[image]

[ref 2](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities)

Comment: +1 This works when you don't have direct access to `WindowManager` (e.g. inside a Loader). Just multiply it by 160

Comment: API Level 16 added xxdpi, which translates here to 3.0.

Comment: this will give 1.3312501 for `tvdpi`. For more info on `tvdpi` see [here](https://plus.google.com/105051985738280261832/posts/6eWwQvFGLV8)

Comment: Nexus 7 reports 1.3, why bracket should that go in?

Comment: Not getting this "x" factor i.e. 0.75x?

Comment: If you need to scale text, I found a way to avoid the API stuff, you can also get the density information from the 1dp value. 
1. Define a dimension in your dimens.xml file, value should be 1dp
2. From your Java code, do `Context#getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(DIMEN_NAME_HERE)`
3. Multiply your pixel value with this value (for hdpi I think it will be the same)

Comment: My phone pulls drawables from xxxdpi, but reports a density of 3.5.  The above chart says "4.0" maps to xxxhdpi.  Which is correct?

Comment: @selbie, your phone is probably pulling and scaling the higher quality resources since your phone is reporting half way between two defined densities.

Comment: @selbie, `...the system prefers to scale-down the high-density version of the resource..` from https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#terms

Comment: What if you get 1.75?

Answer (score 149):

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

switch(metrics.densityDpi) {
     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
         break;

     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
         break;

     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
         break;
}
```

This will work on API level 4 and higher.

Comment: How would you hand devices like Nexus 7 that reports densityDpi as 213?

Comment: have if-else hand check between density value like, if (metrics.densityDpi > DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW && metrics.densityDpi < DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM)

Comment: OR if (metrics.densityDpi < DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW){} else if (metrics.densityDpi < DisplayMetrics. DENSITY_MEDIUM){}.....

Comment: Neil, 213 is called TV DPI, there is a named display metrics density for that DENSITY_TV.

Answer (score 64):

[Blundell's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/413127/blundell) answer as a static helper method:

```
private static String getDensityName(Context context) {
    float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    if (density >= 4.0) {
        return "xxxhdpi";
    }
    if (density >= 3.0) {
        return "xxhdpi";
    }
    if (density >= 2.0) {
        return "xhdpi";
    }
    if (density >= 1.5) {
        return "hdpi";
    }
    if (density >= 1.0) {
        return "mdpi";
    }
    return "ldpi";
}
```

Comment: what about the tvdpi density. I guess it is 1.33

Comment: @AnoopssGolden It's not really standard, so you can add it if you want, but I don't think the answer should include it. From the android docs: "This is not considered a "primary" density group. It is mostly intended for televisions and most apps shouldn't need it".

Comment: But nexus 7 device belong to tvdpi density group.

Comment: @AnoopssGolden Isn't it better to use mdpi for it?

Comment: I know this is a bit old but just to add; MDPI might work for most things on a Nexus 7 but as I am trying now, images coming down as MDPI are not big enough. I am having to define TVDPI and then ask for a bigger image size from my server. It may not be used a lot but that doesn't mean MDPI will pick up everything.

Comment: That code could do with some elses. I hope you don't mind but I added them and removed the braces. It's slightly more efficient now.

Comment: Hey @Andrew S, using elses does not change anything to the efficiency of the code since every if returns immediately. Removing braces is a question of style only and IMHO makes it more error prone when maintaining the code.

Comment: 2020 year: 
This was maybe true before, but take in mind that android evolved. 
For example this would be wrong for Pixel 3a phone which density is 2.75, but according to this documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics#DENSITY_440
It belongs to XXHDPI.

Comment: this method returns `hdpi` for 1.7. But it actually belongs to `xhdpi`

Answer (score 48):

Here are some density constants, [source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html):

[image]

There are, in addition to the standard densities, 5 Intermediate ones. Taking into account this fact, the following code will be a complete working example:

```
float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

if (density == 0.75f)
{
    // LDPI
}
else if (density >= 1.0f && density < 1.5f)
{
    // MDPI
}
else if (density == 1.5f)
{
    // HDPI
}
else if (density > 1.5f && density <= 2.0f)
{
    // XHDPI
}
else if (density > 2.0f && density <= 3.0f)
{
    // XXHDPI
}
else
{
    // XXXHDPI 
}
```

Alternatively, you can find density constants using the `densityDpi`:

```
int densityDpi = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;

switch (densityDpi)
{
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
        // LDPI
        break;

    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
        // MDPI
        break;

    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV:
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
        // HDPI
        break;

    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_280:
        // XHDPI
        break;

    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_360:
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_400:
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_420:
        // XXHDPI
        break;

    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH:
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_560:
        // XXXHDPI
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 45):

Try this:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int densityDpi = dm.densityDpi;
```

Comment: I like this much better since it relies on context rather than activity.

Comment: Agreed, I can use this from a `View` much more easily (which is where I need it!)

Answer (score 38):

To get dpi:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

// will either be DENSITY_LOW, DENSITY_MEDIUM or DENSITY_HIGH
int dpiClassification = dm.densityDpi;

// these will return the actual dpi horizontally and vertically
float xDpi = dm.xdpi;
float yDpi = dm.ydpi;
```

Comment: dm.densityDpi returns either DENSITY_LOW or DENSITY_MEDIUM or DENSITY_HIGH. What about xhdpi? Is there any DENSITY_XHIGH or so?

Comment: Yes, there is: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html

Answer (score 29):

The following answer is a small improvement based upon qwertzguy's answer.

```
double density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
if (density >= 4.0) {
   //"xxxhdpi";
}
else if (density >= 3.0 && density < 4.0) {
   //xxhdpi
}
else if (density >= 2.0) {
   //xhdpi
}
else if (density >= 1.5 && density < 2.0) {
   //hdpi
}
else if (density >= 1.0 && density < 1.5) {
   //mdpi
}
```

Comment: This code could do with some elses, and the ampersands and conditions after it are redundant.

Comment: @Andrew, thanks for the correction. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @San You don't need the && in any of those conditions, as long as you consistently checked for >= the else if will terminate for the first condition that is true.

Comment: This doesn't return a correct result for me with my Nexus 5X (a default google device btw). The device density is xxhdpi, and the double density returned is around 2.6.

Answer (score 21):

Actualy if you want to have the **real display dpi** the answer is somewhere in between
if you query for display metrics:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int dpiClassification = dm.densityDpi;
float xDpi = dm.xdpi;
float yDpi = dm.ydpi;
```

densityDpi * 160 will give you the values/suggestion which density you should use

```
0.75 - ldpi - 120 dpi
1.0 - mdpi - 160 dpi
1.5 - hdpi - 240 dpi
2.0 - xhdpi - 320 dpi
3.0 - xxhdpi - 480 dpi
4.0 - xxxhdpi - 640 dpi
```

as specified in previous posts

but `dm.xdpi` won't give you always the **REAL dpi** of given display:
Example:

```
Device: Sony ericsson xperia mini pro (SK17i)
Density: 1.0 (e.g. suggests you use 160dpi resources)
xdpi: 193.5238
Real device ppi is arround 193ppi


Device: samsung GT-I8160 (Samsung ace 2)
Density 1.5 (e.g. suggests you use 240dpi resources)
xdpi 160.42105
Real device ppi is arround 246ppi
```

so maybe real dpi of the display should be Density*xdpi .. but i'm not sure if this is the correct way to do!

Comment: Using Density*xdpi is working perfectly so far on all my apps on google play so far for the past 6 months

Comment: Multiplying density * xdpi is not logical, which is clearer now that there are more higher density devices - both Density and xdpi increase, so multiplying them would be double-counting the increase. I would say Samsung ace 2 was an error by the vendor. The Android spec is that xdpi and ydpi are the true pixel densities - don't multiply by anything.

Answer (score 18):

This should help on your activity ...

```
void printSecreenInfo(){

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(metrics);

    Log.i(TAG, "density :" +  metrics.density);

    // density interms of dpi
    Log.i(TAG, "D density :" +  metrics.densityDpi);

    // horizontal pixel resolution
    Log.i(TAG, "width pix :" +  metrics.widthPixels);

     // actual horizontal dpi
    Log.i(TAG, "xdpi :" +  metrics.xdpi);

    // actual vertical dpi
    Log.i(TAG, "ydpi :" +  metrics.ydpi);

}
```

OUTPUT :

```
I/test( 1044): density :1.0

I/test( 1044): D density :160

I/test( 1044): width pix :800

I/test( 1044): xdpi :160.0

I/test( 1044): ydpi :160.42105
```

Answer (score 13):

```
public static String getDensity(Context context) {
    String r;
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();

    if (!(context instanceof Activity)) {
        r = "hdpi";
    } else {
        Activity activity = (Activity) context;
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        if (metrics.densityDpi <= DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW) {
            r = "ldpi";
        } else if (metrics.densityDpi <= DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM) {
            r = "mdpi";
        } else {
            r = "hdpi";
        }
    }

    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

If you want to retrieve the density from a Service it works like this:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
```

Comment: This one helped me when i had no windowManager

Answer (score 8):

You Should Try This. Just Added a Method which will find and Show the Toast. That in Which Category the Device Falls.

```
public static int differentDensityAndScreenSize(Context context) {
  int value = 20;
  String str = "";
  if ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL) {
   switch (context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) {
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
    str = "small-ldpi";
    value = 20;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
    str = "small-mdpi";
    value = 20;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
    str = "small-hdpi";
    value = 20;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
    str = "small-xhdpi";
    value = 20;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
    str = "small-xxhdpi";
    value = 20;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH:
    str = "small-xxxhdpi";
    value = 20;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV:
    str = "small-tvdpi";
    value = 20;
    break;
   default:
    str = "small-unknown";
    value = 20;
    break;
   }

  } else if ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL) {
   switch (context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) {
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
    str = "normal-ldpi";
    value = 82;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
    str = "normal-mdpi";
    value = 82;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
    str = "normal-hdpi";
    value = 82;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
    str = "normal-xhdpi";
    value = 90;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
    str = "normal-xxhdpi";
    value = 96;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH:
    str = "normal-xxxhdpi";
    value = 96;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV:
    str = "normal-tvdpi";
    value = 96;
    break;
   default:
    str = "normal-unknown";
    value = 82;
    break;
   }
  } else if ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {
   switch (context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) {
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
    str = "large-ldpi";
    value = 78;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
    str = "large-mdpi";
    value = 78;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
    str = "large-hdpi";
    value = 78;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
    str = "large-xhdpi";
    value = 125;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
    str = "large-xxhdpi";
    value = 125;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH:
    str = "large-xxxhdpi";
    value = 125;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV:
    str = "large-tvdpi";
    value = 125;
    break;
   default:
    str = "large-unknown";
    value = 78;
    break;
   }

  } else if ((context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE) {
   switch (context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) {
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
    str = "xlarge-ldpi";
    value = 125;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
    str = "xlarge-mdpi";
    value = 125;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
    str = "xlarge-hdpi";
    value = 125;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
    str = "xlarge-xhdpi";
    value = 125;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
    str = "xlarge-xxhdpi";
    value = 125;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH:
    str = "xlarge-xxxhdpi";
    value = 125;
    break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV:
    str = "xlarge-tvdpi";
    value = 125;
    break;
   default:
    str = "xlarge-unknown";
    value = 125;
    break;
   }
  }
// The Toast will show the Device falls in Which Categories.
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  return value;
 }
```

http://www.androidwarriors.com/2016/01/how-to-find-different-devices-screen.html

Answer (score 7):

This should work.

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int width = dm.widthPixels; //320
int height = dm.heightPixels; //480
```

Comment: The size in pixels of the display is not the density.

Comment: This is density independent pixels not the pixels. And that 320 you see is 320dip not 320px. The calculation of px is different see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840904/how-to-get-the-screen-size-of-the-device/6841335#6841335

Answer (score 7):

Yet another answer:

```
/**
* @return "ldpi", "mdpi", "hdpi", "xhdpi", "xhdpi", "xxhdpi", "xxxhdpi", "tvdpi", or "unknown".
*/
public static String getDensityBucket(Resources resources) {
    switch (resources.getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) {
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
            return "ldpi";
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
            return "mdpi";
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
            return "hdpi";
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
            return "xhdpi";
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
            return "xxhdpi";
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH:
            return "xxxhdpi";
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV:
            return "tvdpi";
        default:
            return "unknown";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this...

In kotlin

```
fun determineScreenDensityCode(): String {
      return when (resources.displayMetrics.densityDpi) {
         DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW -> "ldpi"
         DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM -> "mdpi"
         DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH -> "hdpi"
         DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH, DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_280 -> "xhdpi"
         DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH, DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_360, DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_400, DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_420 -> "xxhdpi"
         DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH, DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_560 -> "xxxhdpi"
         else -> "Unknown code ${resources.displayMetrics.densityDpi}"
     }
}
```

You can call by `println("density: ${determineScreenDensityCode()}")`
and the output will be `System.out: density: xxxhdpi`

Answer (score 4):

Another way to get the density loaded by the device:

Create `values` folders for each density

- values (default mdpi)
- values-hdpi
- values-xhdpi
- values-xxhdpi
- values-xxxhdpi

Add a string resource in their respective `strings.xml`:

```
<string name="screen_density">MDPI</string>    <!-- ..\res\values\strings.xml -->
<string name="screen_density">HDPI</string>    <!-- ..\res\values-hdpi\strings.xml -->
<string name="screen_density">XHDPI</string>   <!-- ..\res\values-xhdpi\strings.xml -->
<string name="screen_density">XXHDPI</string>  <!-- ..\res\values-xxhdpi\strings.xml -->
<string name="screen_density">XXXHDPI</string> <!-- ..\res\values-xxxhdpi\strings.xml -->
```

Then simply get the string resource, and you have your density:

```
String screenDensity = getResources().getString(R.string.screen_density);
```

If the density is larger than `XXXHDPI`, it will default to `XXXHDPI` or if it is lower than `HDPI` it will default to `MDPI`

[image: R.strings.screen_density values]

I left out `LDPI`, because for my use case it isn't necessary.

Comment: I think this is the right way to get the density. Because I use the
getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density,  the density would change if I changes the display size in setting.

Answer (score 2):

## Kotlin

`LocalContext.current.resources.displayMetrics.density`

To get the density multiplier.

Answer (score 1):

In Android you can get the screen density like this:

```
public static String getScreenDensity(Context context)
{
    String density;
    switch (context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi)
    {
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
            density = "LDPI";
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_140:
            density = "LDPI - MDPI";
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
            density = "MDPI";
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_180:
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_200:
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_220:
            density = "MDPI - HDPI";
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
            density = "HDPI";
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_260:
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_280:
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_300:
            density = "HDPI - XHDPI";
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
            density = "XHDPI";
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_340:
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_360:
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_400:
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_420:
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_440:
            density = "XHDPI - XXHDPI";
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
            density = "XXHDPI";
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_560:
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_600:
            density = "XXHDPI - XXXHDPI";
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH:
            density = "XXXHDPI";
            break;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV:
            density = "TVDPI";
            break;
        default:
            density = "UNKNOWN";
            break;
    }

    return density;
}
```

And in Kotlin like this:

```
fun getScreenDensity(context: Context): String {
    val density: String
    when (context.resources.displayMetrics.densityDpi) {
        DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW -> density = "LDPI"
        DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_140 -> density = "LDPI - MDPI"
        DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM -> density = "MDPI"
        DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_180, DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_200, DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_220 -> density = "MDPI - HDPI"
        DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH -> density = "HDPI"
        DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_260, DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_280, DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_300 -> density = "HDPI - XHDPI"
        DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH -> density = "XHDPI"
        DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_340, DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_360, DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_400, DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_420, DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_440 -> density =
            "XHDPI - XXHDPI"
        DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH -> density = "XXHDPI"
        DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_560, DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_600 -> density = "XXHDPI - XXXHDPI"
        DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH -> density = "XXXHDPI"
        DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV -> density = "TVDPI"
        else -> density = "UNKNOWN"
    }

    return density
}
```

Make sure to regularly [check if new densities are added](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#summary).

Answer (score 1):

For Jetpack compose first get the screen density inside a composable function with

```
var density = LocalDensity.current.density
```

then switch off the density value like the other answers

```
    if (density >= 4.0) {
        return "xxxhdpi";
    }
    if (density >= 3.0) {
        return "xxhdpi";
    }
    if (density >= 2.0) {
        return "xhdpi";
    }
    if (density >= 1.5) {
        return "hdpi";
    }
    if (density >= 1.0) {
        return "mdpi";
    }
    return "ldpi";
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using following code to access DPI from modules (no need for having access to a context object):

```
(Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().xdpi
Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().ydpi)/2
```