# Android Development: Scale to fit different devices

Tags: android, screen, scale, surfaceview

Im making a game and using surfaceview.
I load bitmaps that represent character and background and so on.

But HOW do I properly scale it to fit large devices and small devices and other devices?

//Simon

NOTE* dpi wont work, only pixels work whhen using canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a helper method that you can use to request calculations based on the device's dpi.

Based on @MitulNakum answer from this [qustion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166501/getting-the-screen-density-programmatically-in-android), do this:

```
//note that mdpi is the standard
float getAdjustedDimension(float value){
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    switch(metrics.densityDpi){
         case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
              //api 4 and higher
              return 0.75 * value;
         case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
              //api 4 and higher
              return value;
         case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
              //api 4 and higher
              return value * 1.25;
         case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH
              //api 9 and higher
              return value * 2;
         case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV
              //api 13 and higher
              return value * 1.33125;
    }
}
```

Comment: Two important points, you should probably cache metrics.densityDpi, and this is not very efficient for a game.

Comment: why not return metrics.density * value?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at AndEngine's Cameras. Everything you are looking for can be found there, and it is open source! I have used this engine for a number of games and prototype apps. It is very well documented.

[AndEngine.org](http://www.andengine.org)

[Source Code](http://code.google.com/p/andengine/)

Comment: Sorry but im not intressted in engines :)

Answer (score 0):

The android supported way is by creating several images for each bitmap you need for your app of varying sizes and letting the app decide which to use for a given screen density.  Those images would go in the drawable-ldpi, drawable-hdpi, etc, folders.  Check out the link and read it closly: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Not very memory friendly though. :(