# is the screen from this device belongs to ldpi (or mdpi or hdpi) density?

Tags: android-layout, screen, android, android-gui

I want to write a function like this

```
public boolean isThisScreenWithHdpiDensity(){
    return true/false;
}
```

but I do not know how to calculate this at run time programmatic-ally

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting the screen density programmatically in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166501/getting-the-screen-density-programmatically-in-android)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this inside your function:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
switch(metrics.densityDpi){
     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
                break;
     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
                 break;
     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
                 break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
      public boolean isThisScreenWithHdpiDensity()
      {         
         DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
         getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

         if(metrics.density == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH)
         {
             return true;
         }

         return false;
      }
```