# how to make UI which support all devices without using xml in android?

Tags: android

I am making UI in android using java code because all UI information comming from server so we can't use xml but there is problem when I create 7 button on screen by giving information it is supporting ldpi but rest of devices it is not working code is as-

```
for (int index = 0; index <7; index++) {


        Button objwidgetbutton = new Button(this);


        LinearLayout.LayoutParams objlayoutbtnparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(280,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); // Verbose!

        objwidgetbutton.setText("hiii");

        objwidgetbutton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        llinner.addView(objwidgetbutton,objlayoutbtnparams);

    }
    objlinear.addView(llinner);
```

I am using this structure is as

```
<LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout>
   <button/>#7
  </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Please guide me Is I going right path or doing other things?Main things is that how to make screen support all resolution

Comment: do you mean multi-screen support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to set up some different methodologies for each of the different pixel densities. See [this solution to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5323437/1210260). Adapt your code to work with different pixel densities, and put them in the case statements.