# How to convert resolution to dpi

Tags: android

I did my analysis and found that most of the users of my application will be of samsung galaxy S2, and samsung galaxy note . Doing research on their technical spec, I found:
Galaxy S2:
480 x 800 pixels, 4.3' display

Galaxy Note:
 1280 x 800, 5.3”screen

How can I categorize these into Layout size and desnity level? I think I can figure out the layout size as mentioned in the android development page
However I am unable to know the density level (low, medium high xhigh). They say that I need the dpi but in functional spec, I rarely see the dpi, I just see the above resolution
Thank you

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166501/getting-the-screen-density-programmatically-in-android

Comment: It is totally not a duplicate of it. The other guy is talking about reading the matrics from device, I am talking about conversion by pen and paper!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Calculate the density first **Density=Square root((wp*wp)+(hp*hp))/di**

where wp is width resolution in pixels, hp is height resolution in pixels and di is diagonal size in inches. It would come ~208 for S2.

**ldpi  ~120dpi,mdpi  ~160dpi, hdpi~240dpi, xhdpi ~320dpi**. Compare from these values of dpi

Comment: PERFECT.. That's what Iam looking for exactly Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you correctly but you can request the density level and the dpi from the DisplayMetrics class. Using resolution and density you can approximate the display's size.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
```

Comment: Thanks but thats not what I was asking for, I was asking about how to convert screen resolution to screen density (dpi) by pen and paper