# Smallest Width qualifiers not working

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a "layout" folder and a "layout-sw1024dp" folder, both with a file layout.xml.

In the "layout" folder, I have an ImageView view with the following dimensions:

```
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="150dp"
```

In the "layout-sw1024dp" folder, the dimensions for the same ImageView are:

```
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="300dp"
```

Using GenyMotion, I have two devices with the following dimensions:

- 480x800
- 1080x1920

The problem is that the smaller image dimensions are showing on both devices, when the 1080x1920 device CLEARLY qualifies for the 1024 smallest width.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Which is the size screen of 1080x1920? 1024 smallest width is a density independent pixel dimension, so it changes according to screen pixels and screen wide dimension.

Comment: dp = density independent pixels, you show your Genymotion dimensions but what is the density of the emulator (mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi, etc.)

Comment: The emulator dpi settings for both is 240dpi, so hdpi.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment above by Morrison Chang, I need to take in consideration the dpi of the emulator (device). I found the following calculation to get the actual smallest width dpi:

[How to convert resolution to dpi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179784/how-to-convert-resolution-to-dpi)

Calculate the density:

```
Density=Square root((wp*wp)+(hp*hp))/di
```

where wp is width resolution in pixels, hp is height resolution in pixels and di is diagonal size in inches.