# Force width when generating dynamic linearlayouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm setting up a layout, that I'm adding to (via a for-loop) based on a set of objects. The issue is if there are say 3 fields (columns), if the middle field has a longer text length in the first entry than the second... the middle field in the first one will consume a larger width, even if I've already defined a weightSum and a layout_weight for that center column. My question is, when dynamically adding rows like this, how can I ensure that they all end up being the exact same width, as defined in the XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just set a fixed width?

As in

```
setWidth(int width)
```

EDIT:

The formula to convert px to dpi is:

```
truePixels = DIPs * (device DPI / 160)
```

Here take a look how to get [screen dpi.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166501/getting-the-screen-density-programmatically-in-android)

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) about supporting multiple screens.

Comment: Because my layout is specified using weight, so I don't get odd results on different sized device screens. If I set actual dimensions, it may cause layout issues on smaller screens, vs tablet screens

Comment: You can use DPI so it's compatible with different screens.

Comment: When you use setWidth is it looking for a dpi value? I thought it was in pixels

Comment: you can alwasy get the density screen and multiply the widht

Comment: @RyanInBinary As stated by blackbelt, you can convert px to dpi. Take a look at the edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using xml layout for rows then:

```
android:layout_width="0"
```

If everything is done programmatically then `setWidth(0)`