# Android can i get the device dpi by ppi

Tags: android, dpi, ppi

I am developing an app for multiple screen support.

I just visited the [wiki Android DeviceDensity Comparison page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density).

I want to convert `ppi` to `dpi`.

for example:

Samsung Galaxy Note has a `ppi` of `285` (according to the wiki page).

But in the wiki page the data for `dpi` is not there for every android device.

I want to know how to calculate `dpi` from `ppi`.

For example, the Samsung Galaxy Note has a `ppi` of `285`. How do I calculate the density of the Samsung galaxy note device (in `dpi`).

Answer (score 2):

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

 // Display device width and height in pixels
 screenHeightpx = dm.heightPixels;
 screenWidthpx  = dm.widthPixels;

 // Display device dpi value of X Y in pixels
 screenDPIx = dm.xdpi;
 screenDPIy = dm.ydpi;
```

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

IDK about converting ppi to dpi, as pixels-per-inch is a fix value, dpi dots-per-inch on the other hand depends on the screen density. You can how ever calculate dpi based on ppi and screen density. Here are two examples.

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/07/get-screen-size-in-dpi.html

[getting the screen density programmatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166501/getting-the-screen-density-programmatically-in-android)

mainly Jere.Jones answer.