# getheight() px or dpi?

Tags: android, dpi

Help.I found the height of ListView and I do not know px or dpi? I need dpi

```
final ListView actualListView = mPullRefreshListView.getRefreshableView();

actualListView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        height = actualListView.getHeight();  

                    }
                });
```

Comment: getHeight(); always return height in pixels, check this solution for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166501/getting-the-screen-density-programmatically-in-android

Comment: Just a sidenote for the future. What you need is probably `dp` or `dip` - they stand for *density independent pixels*. `dpi` is *dots per inch* and it measures the density of the screen, not the dimensions.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

*getheight return height in pixels*, Below is what docs says..

```
  public final int getHeight ()
```

> > Since: API Level 1
> >
> > Return the height of your view.
> >     Returns
> >
> > The height of your view, in pixels.

You need to convert px into dp , use below ways to convert it to dp.

**Convert pixel to dp:**

```
public int pxToDp(int px) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int dp = Math.round(px / (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
    return dp;
}
```

or if you want it in px use below.

**Convert dp to pixel:**

```
public int dpToPx(int dp) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int px = Math.round(dp * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));       
    return px;
}
```

Comment: If used in `Fragment`, `getContext()` can produce `NullPointerException`, instead you should get the context in `onCreateView()`, like this 

`Context context = view.getContext();`

Comment: Does it work for "xdpi" only? What happens if this same code is executed in a mdpi device for example?

Answer (score 2):

It returns pixels.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getHeight()
To convert pixels to dpi use this formula  px = dp * (dpi / 160)

Comment: The formula is wrong. It depends on the screen density which will vary for each device...

Answer (score 2):

The functions for converting dp to px and px to dp should look like below (in kotlin):

```
fun convertDpToPx(dp: Int): Int {
    val metrics = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics
    return dp * (metrics.densityDpi / 160f).roundToInt()
  }

fun convertPxToDp(px: Int): Int {
  val metrics = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics
  return (px / (metrics.densityDpi / 160f)).roundToInt()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using this code you can get runtime Display's Width & Height

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int wwidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

Comment: could you please tell me resolution (in dpi) for heights of 458 px ?