# How to get AdView banner height

Tags: android, admob, adview

I'm using Admob AdView (adaptive banner), and I want to get the height of the banner. the banner defined like this:

```
private AdSize getAdSize() { //https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner/adaptive
    // Step 2 - Determine the screen width (less decorations) to use for the ad width.
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(outMetrics);

    float widthPixels = outMetrics.widthPixels;
    float density = outMetrics.density;

    int adWidth = (int) (widthPixels / density);

    // Step 3 - Get adaptive ad size and return for setting on the ad view.
    return AdSize.getCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize(this, adWidth);
  }


  mAdView = new AdView(getContext());
  mAdView.setAdUnitId("00000000000000000000");

    AdSize adSize = new AdSize(getAdSize().getWidth(), (int) ((getAdSize().getHeight()/3)*2.5));//I want the banner to be a bit smaller than returned.

    mAdView.setAdSize(adSize);
    List<String> testDeviceIds = Arrays.asList("00000000000000");
    RequestConfiguration configuration =
            new RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(testDeviceIds).build();
    MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(configuration);

    //insert adView to wrap_content container
    con.addView(mAdView);
    adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

**But the problem is:**
this expression:  `(int) ((getAdSize().getHeight()/3)*2.5)` returns 52 in my case. **but its not the real size of the banner.** (he is bigger).
I tried to print banner's height on click and It turns out that he is actually `136px`.

Is it `setAdSize()` bug? (or maybe it because the ad resolution)?
However , how can I get the **real** height before banner loaded? (without waiting for banner loading like `getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener()` that not working either btw).

I tried using : `mAdview.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);`
and `mAdView.getMeasuredHeight()` but it returns 0.

And I tried `getHeight()`  inside `getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener()` and inside `onAdLoaded()` (even that I want to know the height before loading) but it still 0.

**In summary:**
I have 2 questions:

1. I can see that the banner's height is not `52` as returned from `(int) ((getAdSize().getHeight()/3)*2.5)`. so why `setAdSize()` is faking values? (and how to avoid it)
2. And how can I get the real shown height?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28136027/878126
Try to implement and use runJustBeforeBeingDrawn() method

Comment: Not working either. return 0.

Comment: Why are you using `(int) ((getAdSize().getHeight()/3)*2.5)`? Shouldn't you be using the DPI <-> Pixel calculation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61910409/295004 ?

Comment: the dimensions of `AdSise()` constructor is in `dp`?

Comment: ohhh I'm feeling so dumb. thank you so much!! @MorrisonChang post an answer for winning the bounty   docs: > `width: The width of the ad in density-independent pixels. height: The height of the ad in density-independent pixels.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor for [AdSize (int width, int height)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdSize#public-adsize-int-width,-int-height):

> width: The width of the ad in density-independent pixels.
>
> height: The height of the ad in density-independent pixels.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found way to fix the `getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener()` way by call it after ad loaded:

```
mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                //mAdView.getHeight() returns 0 since the ad UI didn't load
                mAdView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() { 
                        mAdView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                        //mAdView.getHeight() works here
                    }
                });
            }
            
 });
```

And as Morrison Chang said the `width/height` values for `AdSize` constructor should be specified in `dp` not in `px`:

> **width**:    The width of the ad in density-independent pixels. 
> **height**:    The
> height of the ad in density-independent pixels.