# Downloading hdpi, mdpi and ldpi drawables and use them

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to load my drawables for hdpi, mdpi and ldpi from given URLs at runtime and use them ?

If not, how can I overcome the denisity problem ?

Comment: What manner of "density problems" are you having?

Comment: I just want to get support for multiple screen denisity
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support

Comment: That very link contains best practice for this kind of situation - provide drawables for different densities by putting them in a res/ subfolder called drawable-[density], where [density] is ldpi, mdpi, hdpi or xhdpi.

Comment: yes.. and I want to get that functionality dynamically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on screen density you can set the image URL,

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
switch(metrics.densityDpi){
     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
                url = "your_ldpi_url";
                break;
     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
                url = "your_mdpi_url";
                break;
     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH: 
                url = "your_hdpi_url";  
                break;
}
```

And you can fetch that image and use,

```
try {
    InputStream is = (InputStream) this.fetch(url);
    image = Drawable.createFromStream(is,"src");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible. You can't do this after you have built project.
Use this:

```
res/drawable-ldpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for low density
res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really, really want to, you can [get the screen density at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166501/getting-the-screen-density-programmatically-in-android) and [download a bitmap](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html) depending on the result. However, this is an extraordinarily inefficient way to support multiple screen densities, and should be avoided.

If you need to appropriately resize an image that you *have to* download (rather than one that will be present on every run), take a look at the [BitmapDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html) class.