# How to properly organize android drawable resources?

Tags: android, android-resources

I understand that android choices drawables based on their location (-ldpi, -mdpi and so on).    How should I organize my images, if I have two sets of drawables, one for mdpi and ldpi and another for hdpi and xhdpi?

Comment: have you tried putting one set on the mdpi and another on the hdpi?

Comment: @renam.antunes: That won't work. If a device is xhdpi and no drawable is found in the `/drawable-xhdpi` folder, Android will search in the default `/drawable` folder and _not_ in the next-lower-dpi folder: "If no matching resource is available, the system uses the default resource and scales it up or down as needed to match the current screen size and density" from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I didn't come across any possibility to *group* dpi folders.
But you still got choices:

**Dummy drawable:**

Put your images into your normal `/drawable` folder and name them like `image1_low.png` and `image1_high.png`. Now put a "dummy drawable" file `image1_dummy.xml` into your `/drawable-ldpi` *and* `/drawable-mdpi` folders, containing something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/image1_low" />
```

The same goes for the `/drawable-hdpi` *and* `/drawable-xhdpi` folders, but now with `@drawable/image1_high` instead of `@drawable/image1_low`.

Now you can refer to the name of the dummy, e.g. by

`getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image1_dummy);`

in your code to get the desired drawable.

**Programmatical:**

You're not restricted to using folders, there is also a programmatical approach (credits to  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5323437/1140682):

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
switch(metrics.densityDpi){
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
         // assign your high-res version
         break;
   case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
         // assign your high-res version
         break;
   default:
         // assign your low-res version
         break;
}
```