# Converting Pixel values to mm - Android

Tags: android, pixel

Because of specific needs, in my android layout, I have used "mm" to provide size. In TextView also, I have provided sizes in "mm". When I do `textView.getTextSize()`, the size returned is always in pixel values. I want to convert that pixel value in "mm". For example, if I have set font size as "2mm", then on any device, when I do `getTextSize()`, I would like to get "2mm".

Should I use any specific method for that? I could find answers to convert "mm" to "pixel" but could not find anything about converting vice-versa.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

we use [TypedValue.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/util/TypedValue.java)

```
float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_MM, 1, 
                getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

  public static float applyDimension(int unit, float value,
                                       DisplayMetrics metrics)
    {
        switch (unit) {
        case COMPLEX_UNIT_PX:
            return value;
        case COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP:
            return value * metrics.density;
        case COMPLEX_UNIT_SP:
            return value * metrics.scaledDensity;
        case COMPLEX_UNIT_PT:
            return value * metrics.xdpi * (1.0f/72);
        case COMPLEX_UNIT_IN:
            return value * metrics.xdpi;
        case COMPLEX_UNIT_MM:
            return value * metrics.xdpi * (1.0f/25.4f);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

So you can try

Pix = mm * metrics.xdpi * (1.0f/25.4f);

MM = pix / metrics.xdpi * 25.4f;

Comment: Thanks Nimish, your answer seems correct to me. I have edited it a bit - added brackets - float mm = pix /(dm.xdpi * (1.0f/25.4f));

Comment: hmm... strange but breaks are still absent.

Comment: I edited it too: MM = pix / metrics.xdpi * 25.4f; Maybe they will accept my edit...

Comment: the formula is correct as originally written. <p/>please ignore the edits

Answer (score 8):

I'd say a more robust method (which evolves with whatever new insight is applied in the Android framework) is this:

```java
public static float pxToMm(final float px, final Context context)
{
    final DisplayMetrics dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return px / TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_MM, 1, dm);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking with this link.  You are looking for screen pixel density.

[getting the screen density programmatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166501/getting-the-screen-density-programmatically-in-android)

From here you can use inches to mm conversions (1 inch == 25.4 mm) to get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option from google: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html

You'll need to scale this number to mm so use 25.4mm = 1 inch.

Answer (score -2):

```
float mm = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 1, 
            getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

[applyDimesion parameters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html#applyDimension%28int,%20float,%20android.util.DisplayMetrics%29)

Comment: This will return pixel value as is.