# DisplayMetrics is returning zero

Tags: android, dpi

I want to get the dpi of the device's screen but 
when I use:

```
          DisplayMetrics m = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
                float den = m.density;
```

I get the full `DisplayMetrics` object as zero (I saw it in the debugging).
It was the same also in my emulator (android 2.3) and on my phone (Htc Legend android 2.1 update 1).
The code is located in my activity class(`extends Activity`) and then

`WebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient() {`

```
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

              DisplayMetrics m = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
                float den = m.density;
```

}

How can I fix It?

Thank You,

Boaz

Comment: In what kind of class is this code located? Is it a subclass of Activity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166501/getting-the-screen-density-programmatically-in-android):

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
switch(metrics.densityDpi){
     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
                break;
     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
                 break;
     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
                 break;
}
```

Try it out and get back here with the results :)

Cheers

Comment: Why do you have to do that?