# how to find the ppi of an android screen

Tags: java, android

I have a very simple question.

All I'm looking for is the code to find the **PPI** of an android screen, i know how to find the height and width in pixels but not the amount of pixels per inch. I need this to help me find the diagonal of the screen. I tried but it doesn't seem to work

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE); 

int  ppi = (int) displayMetrics.density;
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this?

```
   DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166501/getting-the-screen-density-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: so i got it to work howeever it is not extremly acurate it seems to be of by almost 10%