# How can I have Views on an AlertDialog show on a new line if they don't fit?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

I currently have an `AlertDialog` showing in my app to add a category and products (the app is a shopping list). The categories can have colours, and for that I set up 8 `ImageButtons`, each with a different background. The thing is, that if I have 6 per row, it looks good on hdpi, but it doesn't fit on mdpi. If I have 4 per row, it looks good on mdpi, but not on hdpi. How could I make the `AlertDialog` look good on every device?

Comment: Layout code: https://github.com/zyngawow/ShoppingList/blob/master/ShoppingList/src/main/res/layout/dialog_add_category.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a separate 'layout-mdpi' folder in which you store your dialog_add_category.xml layout file that has 4 per row, and in your default 'layout' folder have a dialog_add_category.xml which has 6 per row.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166501/getting-the-screen-density-programmatically-in-android), specifically the 2nd answer. If the density is mdpi, choose to only put 4 per row. If hdpi, set to 8 per row. May have to make a few layouts for each density.

Answer (score 0):

If your number of buttons are fixed, then you can add a scrollview inside your AlertDialog view, Other wise if number of buttons are flexible then you can add listview also...

Comment: I already have the ImageButtons in a ListView. Adding a ScrollView will not fix my problem as I want to solve it.

Comment: @zyngawow Well.. If you can post some screenshot or your layout/Code to explain your problem...Then only the scenario can be made clear of your exact problem

Comment: Here is my layout code. https://github.com/zyngawow/ShoppingList/blob/master/ShoppingList/src/main/res/layout/dialog_add_category.xml