# canvas.getDensity returning 0

Tags: android, canvas

i'm attempting to draw pixel density independent shapes to the screen. I assume i need canvas.getDensity(), as there is no action like

canvas.drawCircle(cx,cy,60di,paint). //di: density independent pixel

canvas.getDensity() is returning 0, however. I saw on a different post a suggestion of disabling the GPU to fix this. I don't want to disable the GPU on my user's phones' though, even if I knew how. how do I get around this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting the screen density programmatically in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166501/getting-the-screen-density-programmatically-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this here:
[getting the screen density programmatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166501/getting-the-screen-density-programmatically-in-android)

Use getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density or context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density
to get:

0.75 - ldpi

1.0 - mdpi

1.5 - hdpi

2.0 - xhdpi

3.0 - xxhdpi

4.0 - xxxhdp