# Calculate how much DPI width does device have

Tags: java, android

In [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) says, that I can use alternate resources for devices that (for example) has minimum available width in dp units at which the resources should be used—defined by the  value.

So by creating "w720dp" folder, creates resources for particular tablets.
I would like to know how programatically calculate how much width does particular device have.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this may help (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166501/getting-the-screen-density-programmatically-in-android) tells you the dpi and the width in pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the pixels

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```

and then divide them by the pixel density

```
float density  = metrics.density;
```