# Using different fonts for different screen densities

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an Android app on my Nexus 5 device (~445 ppi) and I'm using Roboto Light as the font for a few sections in the application.
When displayed in my device, the Roboto Light text looks clean and crisp, however when testing the app on device with screens that have a lower pixel density, Roboto Light looks pretty bad (bolder fonts look OK).

What is the best and quickest way to tell my app to use Roboto Light on high-density screens and another font on low-density ones? My first idea was to create different `values` directories (values-mdpi, values-hdpi, values-xhdpi...), place a `strings.xml` in each one with the same key and assign it the font's filename I wish to use for each density, and then load the font using that string... however that looks a bit complicated and I was wondering if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

int densityDpi = (int)(metrics.density)

depends on your density you can set font type to textview and other controls like below code use

Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "/fonts/Avenir.ttf");

textView.setTypeface(font);

Comment: That's what I ended up doing (I created a new static method that returned the Typeface object created from asset by the display density). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this programmatically by

> float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
>
> This will give you:
>
> 0.75 - ldpi
>
> 1.0 - mdpi
>
> 1.5 - hdpi
>
> 2.0 - xhdpi
>
> 3.0 - xxhdpi
>
> 4.0 - xxxhdpi
>
> [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10948031/3249477)

Then check the density and act accordingly:

```
if (density >= 2.0) {
    textView.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);
} else {
    textView.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF,Typeface.BOLD);
}
```