# How to know the SIZE TYPE OF the phone in Android

Tags: android

I want to make a method that returns the screen size type (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi or xxhdpi).

And I don't know how to do that.

I tried something like :

```
public static String getSizeType()
{
     if( Phone.icon.getWidth() == 36 )
        return "ldpi";

     if( Phone.icon.getWidth() == 48 )
        return "mdpi";

     if( Phone.icon.getWidth() == 72 )
        return "hdpi";

     if( Phone.icon.getWidth() == 96 )
        return "xhdpi";

     return "xxhdpi";
}

private staic ImageView icon;
public Phone(Context context)
{
    Phone.icon = new ImageView(context);
    Phone.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
}
```

I have 4 icon images for each folder (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi).
That method always returns "xxhdpi" and I don't know why.
What can I do better ?
Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166501/getting-the-screen-density-programmatically-in-android

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make a method that returns the screen size type (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi or xxhdpi).

"ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi or xxhdpi" are screen *densities*. They have nothing to do with screen *sizes*.

> And I don't know how to do that.

`getResources().getConfiguration().densityDpi` returns the density bucket being used by the device, in `dpi`. Note that not all `densityDpi` values will necessarily line up with names like `xhdpi`.