# Using layout-sw(N)dp on Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I read [this official](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts) link because i want to set different XML for larger screen.

First, i checked my device's width (in `dp`) with this code :

```
private void getScreenDp() {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

    float dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;
    float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;
}
```

The width is 320dp.

Then i create a new folder called `layout-sw320dp`. When i run the app in `320dp` width device, its using `layout-sw320dp` correctly.

However, the layout that my apps used when running in `600dp` width device is the one in `layout-sw320dp` instead of the normal `layout` folder. I tried to change the layout to `layout-w320dp` but the devices bigger than `320dp` width still not using the normal layout as it should be.

Please kindly help me,  i have spent hours for this.

Comment: [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts) they say: `Note: Remember that all the figures used with these new size APIs are density-indpendent pixel (dp) values and your layout dimensions should also always be defined using dp units`.  
And they define the dp [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#terms): `The conversion of dp units to screen pixels is simple: px = dp * (dpi / 160).` - I hope it helps.

Comment: @DerGolem Thanks. Do you mean the code i used to count the `dp` is wrong?

Comment: Well, suppose that your tablet width is 1024 px (in landscape orientation). With a density of 320 dpi. Then the dp is `dp = px / (dpi / 160)` => `dp = 1024 / (320 / 160)` => `dp = 1024 / 2` => **dp = 512**

Comment: @DerGolem Thanks a lot, i will try to re-count the `dp` tommorow. Hope its working :D

Comment: Don't forget that you have to provide another folder for the portrait mode. Supposing the with in portrait mode is 768 px, then the dp is **384** (for a screen density of 320 dpi).

Comment: This is how to get the device density (other than getting it from the manufacturer site product specifications): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166501/getting-the-screen-density-programmatically-in-android