# How to get the pixels in a cellphone whose system is android 4.4.2

Tags: android, pixel

I want to get pixels in nubia z7 mini,whose system is android 4.4.2,but i failed.
my code is below:

```
 DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    String strOpt = "PIXEL：" + 
           dm.widthPixels + " × " + dm.heightPixels;
```

I get is 320 * 569 ,but the pixel of my phone can't be that;
then i print density,i  found it is 1.0,i can't know why;

```
 context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density
```

where was my error???How to get the pixels in a cellphone???

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166501/getting-the-screen-density-programmatically-in-android

Comment: If you need the actual lcd pixel density  you can get it from the metrics.xdpi and metrics.ydpi properties for horizontal and vertical density respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try accessing through the Display class.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);

String strOpt = "PIXEL：" + size.x + " × " + size.y;
```