# Which DPI bucket is my display

Tags: android

I am working on an Android application and I try to understand which DPI is my display. The vendor said is an HDPI display but I get a complete different result. This is my code:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

String text = "Width: " + metrics.widthPixels
        + "\nHeight: " + metrics.heightPixels
        + "\nDpi: " + metrics.densityDpi
        + "\nXDPI: " + metrics.xdpi
        + "\nYDPI: " + metrics.ydpi
        + "\nRDpi: " + (int)(metrics.density * 160f);
```

And the device print the following information:

```
Width: 320
Height: 320
Dpi: 160
XDPI: 262
YDPI: 262
RDPI: 160
```

So it seems that the vendor consider XDPI and XDPI the parameters to state that the display is an HDPI but in reality it is an MDPI. Am I wrong?

Comment: it's mdpi. Which device do you have?

Comment: It is not a commercial product, it's a custom Android Wear prototype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to get the DPI is to generate a string.xml file for every density.

Create folders called values-mdpi, values-hdpi, values-xhdpi... and add a strings.xml in everyone, with a string called density with the value of the density (mdpi for strings.xml located in values-mdpi, etc)

then reading R.string.density will give you the correct density

Comment: I can confirm that using this approach I get back the string MDPI, so the vendor use the XDPI and YDPI to sell the display as an HDPI (260) but in reality is an MDPI

Answer (score 0):

120dpi = ldpi
160dpi = mdpi
240dpi = hdpi

So you are on mdpi

Answer (score 0):

As stated by  [joshperry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166501/getting-the-screen-density-programmatically-in-android?answertab=votes#tab-top) The metrics.density property is a floating point scaling factor from the reference density (160dpi). The same value now provided by metrics.densityDpi can be calculated

```
int densityDpi = (int)(metrics.density * 160f);
```