# Layout displayed differently on different devices at the same resolution screen

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-resolution, screen-density

Problem: layout displayed differently on different devices at the same resolution screen. I tested it on *Samsung Galaxy S4* (1080x1920) and on *LG G2* (1080x1920). It the same resolution, so why layout is displayed differently on each device ?

I have all in layout folder and not have another layouts for other resolutions.

Here are screens:

- Samsung Galaxy S4

http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-2963-272.html

- LG G2

http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-2963-271.html

EDIT #1

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/layoutMain"
tools:mContext="com.test.app.flock.mActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewImageBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/viewBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background01" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/viewFingerprint"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fingerprint01"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonScanning"
    android:layout_width="162dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="41dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewScanner"
    android:layout_width="162dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="41dp"
    android:src="@drawable/line01"

    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewResult"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="180dp"

    android:text="SCANNING"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"

    android:visibility="gone" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <DigitalClock
        android:id="@+id/digitalClock"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="7"

        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewDate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="10"

        android:text="10 Grudzien 2015"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's about the density of the pixels.But you should have no problems since you use XML for the UI and you give the widths and heights in DP (density pixel).

Comment: Layout is displayed in different way only on S4. On other devices with the same screen resolution everythink is good. So where is problem here?

Comment: Have you solve this issue? I have the same problem: http://new.izigo.pt/content/images/IMG_3209.JPG

Comment: @Patrick, what is the [screen density](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3166501/3290339) reported by _Android_ for each of the devices?

Comment: @Onik Hi thanks! Can I get this information directly from the device interface? Lenovo (https://www.gsmarena.com/lenovo_tab3_7-7951.php) website says: "600 x 1024 pixels, 16:9 ratio (~170 ppi density)" and Huawei (https://www.gsmarena.com/huawei_mediapad_t3_7_0-8635.php) says: "600 x 1024 pixels, 16:9 ratio (~170 ppi density)". I only find the difference: 7.0 inches, 137.9 cm2 (~72.2% screen-to-body ratio) and 7.0 inches, 137.9 cm2 (~74.3% screen-to-body ratio)

Comment: @Patrick, the key point here is to look how the system treats the displays. The info on the Internet is just a spec...

Comment: @Onik I get 213 (pixels/inch) in the Huawei (scale 1.3) and 160 in the Lenovo (scale (1.0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phones do have the same resolution, however, the window height is different because LG G2 has navigation keys on the screen.

Comment: Hm, is true. So how can i fix it? How to create separate layouts?

Comment: Instead of trying to position the views absolutely so it *seems* they have a background of their own, make one background for the whole screen and backgrounds for each view

Comment: Maybe is a way to do two xml files for device with navigation bar and without?

Comment: It is but you will not end with just two xmls. Basically you would need a xml per device to be 100% sure it will look properly

Comment: I have the same problem and I don't have the navigation keys visible: http://new.izigo.pt/content/images/IMG_3209.JPG any ideia how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in layout or density, but in the different heights available, due to the presence of the button bar.
As the image set as `background` of the `View` will expand, distorting itself, I suggest you to put it as `src` of the `ImageView` and set the `scaleType` to `fitCenter`, this way the image will fit the screen maintaining its proportions:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/background01" />
```

Comment: Hi thanks! In my case, it's a webView with a loadUrl, so I don't have access to the image, it's in the HTML.