# xxhdpi screen in different devices is different

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 2 device with xxhdpi screen,one is genymotion the other is real device ,in dimens.xml file for xxhdpi I have set sizes bigger than xhdpi but in genymotion it seems that I should set smaller sizes in it and in the real device bigger size ,here are the devices screenshots[image]

[image]

i dont know why something like this is happening , can someone tell what to do to have proper dimetions in all devices?many tnx

Comment: try sdp library 
https://github.com/intuit/sdp and https://github.com/intuit/ssp for text size

Comment: are you talking about drawables? If yes, what are the size of the ones in xxhdpi folder? Also could you post your xml file?

Comment: @JacobCelestine no just the pink card has 10 dp padding in dimens.xml(xxhdpi) ,but in genymotion its padding is bigger and in real device is smaller , I want the padding size in genymotion be just like the real device ,not so much big cause they are both xxhdpi

Comment: Just to be clear, the dimens.xml for xxhdpi is defined isnode res/values-xxhdpi/dimens.xml right? If not, I think I can answer your question.

Comment: @JacobCelestine yes its exactly in this path that u said :(

Comment: hmm, in that case, I'm guessing you are using two devices with the same resolution but different height or width. If that's the case I suggest you take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546303 . I'm sorry but I've no other way to help you.