# Resources for multiple screen sizes

Tags: android

As far as I know it is possible to provide multiple resource paths for multiple dpis (mdpi, hdpi etc.).  What if I want to support multiple screen sizes at the same dpi?

For example, if I have an application that draws an icon whose size is always a percentage of the screen size (e. g. 25 %) and I replace the screen by a larger one with the same dpi, then the icon has to be scaled up. This will make the icon blurry unless I provide a version with a higher resolution.  Since Android only distinguishes by dpi and not by screen size, how can I do this?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this question?

Answer (score 0):

If the icon is included in the APK, you may as well just put just one copy - the highest resolution you have.  Large icons can be scaled *down* just fine, it's scaling small icons *up* that causes the blurriness.  The reason for including different sizes is to save bandwidth when icons are downloaded, but since all the copies would already be on the device, in effect all you will be doing is making the APK bigger.  First prize would be to include a vector image (infinitely scalable, small size).

You should also note that the blurriness is really only in comparison with the sharpness of the rest of the display. In reality the 2x scaled-up icons would look just as good as the same icons on a display with a density half as much.

If, however, you still want to select a certain copy of an image based on the dpi and screen size, there are ways you can detect this in Android.  [See this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166501/getting-the-screen-density-programmatically-in-android), for example.