# Relationship between mobile densities?

Tags: android, screen-density

What are the relationship between mobile densities? I know that

ldpi: 0.75
mdpi: 1.0 (base density)
hdpi: 1.5
xhdpi: 2.0
xxhdpi: 3.0
xxxhdpi: 4.0
large: ?
xlarge: ?

What are the relationships for large and xlarge?

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting the screen density programmatically in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166501/getting-the-screen-density-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: How is that a duplicate? The question has nothing to do with programmatically getting the screen density

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- ldpi    = 1:0.75
- mdpi    = 1:1
- hdpi    = 1:1.5
- xhdpi   = 1:2
- xxhdpi  = 1:3
- xxxhdpi = 1:4

Answer (score 0):

Large, xlarge etc. aren't density but screen size qualifiers.
There's no clear definition for small, normal, large and xlarge screen sizes (unlike for densities). Check out this table:

[image]

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing