# How to get Device DPI programmatically?

Tags: java, android, hdpi

How to get Device DPI programmatically.  i need that value not a device like HDPI or MDPI

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
switch(metrics.densityDpi){
     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
                break;
     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
                 break;
     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
                 break;
}
```

this code shows only High or low but i need Value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting the screen density programmatically in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166501/getting-the-screen-density-programmatically-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

// will either be DENSITY_LOW, DENSITY_MEDIUM or DENSITY_HIGH
int dpiClassification = dm.densityDpi;

// these will return the actual dpi horizontally and vertically
 float xDpi = dm.xdpi;
 float yDpi = dm.ydpi;
```

Comment: PPI and DPI both are same ??

Answer (score 0):

Use `metrics.xdpi` and `metrics.ydpi`.

Comment: PPI and DPI both are same ??

Comment: - DPI refers to the number of printed dots contained within one inch of an image.
- PPI refers to the number of pixels contained within one inch of an image.