# Determine at runtime which layout was used

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a number of different layouts for different display sizes (see screen shot). Is it possible to determine programmatically, at runtime, which was used?

[image: res]

**Edit: Suggestion was made to use this:**

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
float density = displayMetrics.density;
```

This returns 0 for 3 devices: Samsung T530NU, ASUS Nexus 7, Droid Maxx
This code:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int densityDpi = (int)(metrics.density * 160f);
```

**returns the following:**

```
Samsung T530NU: 160  
ASUS Nexus 7: 320  
Droid Maxx: 320
```

**Edit 2:**
I implemented something simlar to @Selvin's suggestion:

Create these folders in res:

```
values-large-land  
values-med-land  
values-small-land  
values-xlarge-land  
values-large-port  
values-med-port  
values-small-port  
values-xlarge-port
```

Each folder contains a file called strings.xml
Each strings.xml contains a string called device_size:

```
<string name="device_size">small-land</string>
```

with the value changing with the folder. For the default strings.xml file in the values folder, I assign this:

```
<string name="device_size">unknown</string>
```

Then you can refer to the string:

```
String device_size = getResources().getString(R.string.device_size);
```

**This returns:**

```
Samsung T530NU: xlarge-land    
ASUS Nexus 7: large-land  
Droid Maxx: unknown
```

I'm not sure why the unknown on the Droid Maxx.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/10948031/418505

Comment: You can use `Configuration` to see what resources might qualify. You cannot directly determine what layout gets used, though, by any means that I can think of.

Comment: you may create coresponding values with fx string resources ... in `values-med-land/test.xml`  with `<string name="test">med-land</string>` ... and so on ... then you can get this value ....

Comment: @Selecsosi: see edit please.

Comment: @Selvin:  That's a clever idea. I've implemented something like that now. Please post your suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not any resource folder qualifier names as `med` !

You should use `normal` instead. For example :

```
values-normal-land
values-normal-port
```

for more information refer this link from google.

[Providing Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

Comment: That works, but I don't get it:   
Why would I get an error with `values-xxlarge-land` folder but not `values-med-land` folder?

Comment: maybe med refer to a qualifier. locale name for example. that is why you do not see any error. @AlLelopath