# Android : set width and height of bitmap base on screen size programmatically

Tags: android, bitmap

let say I have Bitmap A with the dimensions **165x15.7** which is displayed correctly on **320x240** screen size with **0.75** density. if i want to show the bitmap images on different screen size like **480x320** with **1.0** density, how to set the bitmap width and height dynamically on different screen size? i want to do it programmatically,I don't want to use xml/ multiple layouts/ multiple dimensions.
any help would be appreciated. thank you.

here is for the example

**320x240 screen dimension**

[image]

**480x320 screen dimension**

[image]

as you can see the screenshot above, the example logo look smaller on 480x320 screen dimension

Comment: so you want to *resize* your `Bitmap` at runtime? why? what is the reason for that? it only takes your device cpu and memory and gives you nothing

Comment: not at run time, per different screen size. @pskink

Comment: `"i want to do it programmatically,"` so what does it mean if no at runtime?

Comment: i meant using java not using xml @pskink

Comment: ok so back to my original question... why do you want to resize your `Bitmap` at runtime? when your android app executes...

Answer (score 2):

You can get the scale factor of device screen to scale the image size with this code :

```
getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

This will give you:

ldpi = 0.75

mdpi = 1.0

hdpi = 1.5

xhdpi = 2.0

xxhdpi = 3.0

xxxhdpi = 4.0

source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10948031/6217595