# How to create QR not using zxing in android?

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I need to create a QR Code following configuration below:

```
 - Model 2
 - Version 10
 - Size 57 x 57 
 - Level H (30%)
 - Max 174 alphanumeric characters or 119 binary
 - Modules size 0.03 inch
```

Actually, I'm using zxing to create the QR but I can't figure out how to set these 3 configurations

```
- Model 2
- Max 174 alphanumeric characters or 119 binary
- Modules size 0.03 inch
```

And this the code I'm using (Kotlin)

```
        imgQrCode.run{setImageBitmap(BarcodeEncoder().createBitmap(
             MultiFormatWriter().encode(content, 
                                        BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 
                                        57, 57,
                                        mapOf<EncodeHintType, Any>(
                                           Pair(EncodeHintType.QR_VERSION, 10),
                                           Pair(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.H)

    ))))}
```

Any idea how can I set those configurations with zxing or is there any alternative option to archive all the factors above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Model 2

1. ZXing appears to be supporting Model 2 QR Code as the code:
   https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/qrcode/encoder/Encoder.java#L280

   seems to handle versions 1 through 40. Model 1 only goes up to version 14.

> Max 174 alphanumeric characters or 119 binary

2. Count? Or use the rough metric from [QR Code Storage section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code) which lists 5.5 bits for Alphanumeric and 8 bits for binary. Do realize that changing error correction will change the number of bits/modules used in the image.

> Modules size 0.03 inch

3. This is a display density question, calculate via [Getting the screen density programmatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3166501/295004).